# How is the best way to completely change a file content in C?

Tags: c, file

I am looking for the faster way to completely change the content of a file. It will be clear after the example:

**a.txt**:

> I am a very very long (maybe not too long) file. I am pretty sure I could be longer.

After running the program, and according to the user's input it should become for instance:

**user input**:

> Hi!

Then I tried to use `fwrite`.
The problem is that the rest of the file were still there, so I've got something like:

**a.txt**:

> Hi!m a very very long (maybe not too long) file. I am pretty sure I could be longer

After some researching this is what I've done:

```
FILE
    *a;

char
    buffer[500];

a = fopen("a.txt", "r");
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 500, a);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

a = freopen("a.txt", "w", a);

    scanf("%s", buffer);

            // rewind(a);
            // fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), a);

    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 10, a);
    fclose(a);
```

Although it works, I want to know if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: depending on your requirements a more structured format could be appropriate, such as xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `ftruncate()` POSIX function after `fwrite()` to truncate the file.

Comment: I think you'd also have to do something about the stdio buffers.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard What do you mean? How it is related to stdio and its buffering?

Comment: Consider [this little program I wrote](http://paste.lisp.org/+2W1S).  It seems to work as expected resulting in a five-byte output file.  However, on my system at least, if you remove the `fflush` call you end up with a ten-byte output file, presumably because the actual `write` call occurs after the `ftruncate` call.  I'm fairly confident there would be some other scenarios that could cause trouble, especially if you are both reading and writing the file.

Answer (score 0):

The "w" flag should create a file, truncating any existing content if it exists. That's what you need.

I haven't used `freopen()` before but suspect that's related to the problem. I would try simply closing the input file with `fclose()`, and then open the file again using `fopen()`?

Comment: Well... This is basically what this `freopen()` is doing, isn't it?

Comment: Well, you are seeing non-standard behavior for `fopen()` and it would probably take you all of 2 seconds to find our for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a better way to do this using portable C.

There are a few minor problems with your implementation.

You don't check for any errors that might have occurred, which is important in the real world.  Especially `freopen` might return `NULL` on error, and if you assign that to you're original pointer you lose the ability to `fclose` the file.

You should also remember that normal C strings end with a 0 byte, but `fread` reads raw bytes so you should reserve space for that zero byte and provide it.  `scanf` will write the zero byte so you can use `strlen` to determine how many bytes to tell `fwrite` to write instead of hardcoding 10.

Finally `scanf` is easy for mocking stuff up, but the way you have it now if the user provides more than 499 bytes you'll have a buffer overflow which can lead to very bad things.